# results ordering by the query string

Tags: sql, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

How do I query so that I get results which are ordered by prefix.

For example, for a query where querystring is say `o`, It should return results like

```
["oat", "osborne", "aol", "bot"]
```

for query string `fin`

```
["fine", "finish", "define", "refine"]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: post you document structure. What about using regex?

Comment: This is tagged with SQL and Nosql... which is it...?

Comment: I got a feeling you wish to order by relevance of a query string, you want an fts tech, or you could try mongodbs fts abilities or whatever

Answer (score 0):

The database (MongoDB) can not sort by arbitrary value, so you will have to do this in your application. This is a very specific type of sorting, and I doubt you would fine any database that can do this—except for perhaps SQLite where you can call out into your (scripting) language to set your sorting comparison function.